# Spark not compressing json output

Tags: apache-spark

I've added the following to my script:

```
val conf = new SparkConf
conf.set("spark.hadoop.mapred.output.compress", "true")
conf.set("spark.hadoop.mapred.output.compression.codec", "true")
conf.set("spark.hadoop.mapred.output.compression.codec", "org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec")
conf.set("spark.hadoop.mapred.output.compression.type", "BLOCK")
```

And I write the data like this `df.write.json("out")`. However, all I get is .json files in the output and not .json.gz as expected. What's wrong here?

Comment: Could be that you're using deprecated properties: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/DeprecatedProperties.html

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but changing to new properties does not help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec

val df = Seq((2012, 8, "Batman", 9.8), (2012, 8, "Hero", 8.7), (2012, 7, "Robot", 5.5), (2011, 7, "Git", 2.0)).toDF("year", "month", "title", "rating")
df.toJSON.rdd.saveAsTextFile("/tmp/jsonRecords", classOf[GzipCodec])
```